# How to display random gifs consecutively in a picturebox

Tags: .net, vb.net, picturebox, gif

I'm making a title screen for a class project and I've downloaded a bunch of gifs to show. I have a timer on it that just ticks on a constant interval. I want the picture to change when the gif is over. I've been at it forever and still haven't found a way to do it. Thanks for the help

Comment: Show us the code you have and what error you're getting or what specifically is not behaving as expected.

Comment: Post some examples of what you've tried so far.  You say that you have a timer on a constant interval, but you want the picture to change when the gif has run its cycle.  Does that mean each gif runs the same cycle in unison with your timer?

Answer (score 0):

The only ways I can think of to do this would be to either determine the length of each .gif prior to build time [using a tool like ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812589/how-to-determine-the-length-of-a-gif-animation-in-milliseconds) (and feed that into your application).  Or to find some interface that allows you to interact at [a low level with the .gif format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347887/how-to-get-length-in-time-from-an-animated-gif).  In my opinion, the first is more feasible, but pretty complicated, the second is less likely to work out.  To my knowledge, there's no low-level interface (similar to what you describe) with the .gif format in VB.